# Comparing 2 uneven lists consists of dictionaries with unique keys in python and search key value in a but not in b

Tags: python, list, dictionary, comparison, key-value

Hi all I'm still at learning stage of python and looking for help in list of dictionary.

Having two list of dictionary a1 and p1, we are trying to take out "Code" which are present a1 but not present in p1 and also if Code present and not p1 then it's IsRemoved should have value 0 i.e., [IsRemoved] == 0

```
a1 = [{'Code': '1', 'Name': 'ven1', 'DomainName': 'xyz.com', 'IsRemoved': 0}, {'Code': '2', 'Name': 'ven2', 'DomainName': 'abc.co.in', 'IsRemoved': 1}, {'Code': '3', 'Name': 'ven3', 'DomainName': 'abc.com', 'IsRemoved': 0}, {'Code': 'v001', 'Name': 'ven1', 'DomainName': 'xyz.com|abc.com', 'IsRemoved': 0},{'Code': '4', 'Name': 'ven4', 'DomainName': 'xyz.com', 'IsRemoved': 0}, {'Code': '5', 'Name': 'ven5', 'DomainName': 'abc.com', 'IsRemoved': 0}, {'Code': '6', 'Name': 'ven6', 'DomainName': 'xyz.com', 'IsRemoved': 0}, {'Code': '7', 'Name': 'ven7', 'DomainName': 'xyz.com', 'IsRemoved': 1}, {'Code': '8', 'Name': 'ven8', 'DomainName': 'abc.co.in', 'IsRemoved': 0}, {'Code': '9', 'Name': 'ven9', 'DomainName': 'xyz.com', 'IsRemoved': 1}, {'Code': '10', 'Name': 'ven10', 'DomainName': 'xyz.com', 'IsRemoved': 0}, {'Code': '11', 'Name': 'ven6', 'DomainName': 'xyz.com', 'IsRemoved': 0}, {'Code': 'v001', 'Name': 'ven1', 'DomainName': 'xyz.com|abc.com', 'IsRemoved': 1}, {'Code': 'v002', 'Name': 'ven2', 'DomainName': 'xyz.com|abc.com', 'IsRemoved': 0}]
    
p1 = [{'Code': '1', 'Name': 'ven1', 'Domain': ['xyz.com']}, {'Code': '2', 'Name': 'ven2', 'Domain': ['abc.co.in']}, {'Code': '3', 'Name': 'ven3', 'Domain': ['abc.com']}, {'Code': '4', 'Name': 'ven4', 'Domain': ['xyz.com']}, {'Code': '5', 'Name': 'ven5', 'DomainName': 'abc.com' ]
```

So here I'm expecting output as:

```
{'Code': 'v001', 'Name': 'ven1', 'DomainName': 'xyz.com|abc.com', 'IsRemoved': 0}
{'Code': '6', 'Name': 'ven6', 'DomainName': 'xyz.com', 'IsRemoved': 0}
{'Code': '8', 'Name': 'ven8', 'DomainName': 'abc.co.in', 'IsRemoved': 0}
{'Code': '10', 'Name': 'ven10', 'DomainName': 'xyz.com', 'IsRemoved': 0}
{'Code': '11', 'Name': 'ven6', 'DomainName': 'xyz.com', 'IsRemoved': 0}
{'Code': 'v002', 'Name': 'ven2', 'DomainName': 'xyz.com|abc.com', 'IsRemoved': 0}
```

I tried it out using for loop with != in below way:

```
for x in a1:
    for y in p1:
        if x["Code"] != y["Code"] and x["IsRemoved"] == 0:
            print(x)
```

When I'm trying to find == it works fine and giving me correct result but strange it's not working correctly for !=

Please have a look and guide if I can use some other method to get the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is way you can try out, create unique codes from `p1` & use list comprehension to apply filter on `a1`.

```
unique = {p['Code'] for p in p1} # use set for faster lookup

[a for a in a1 if a['Code'] not in unique and a['IsRemoved'] == 0]
```

Comment: Thanks Sushanth I tried it's giving me the required result